# while (line = readline())

Tags: javascript, input, user-input, readline

I'm new to JavaScript and are trying to solve a problem. I shall only write in JavaScript and the instructions are telling me to use readline(), for example like this: while (line = readline())

But I cant get how this works and I cant find any information about this in JavaScript. I want to get a users input and then put that in a variable. But when I try "while (line = readline())" I can's se anything happen (like with propt, which is the only way I know)...

Thankful for your help!

Here is my code (which works if I use alert and prompt istead of print and readline):

```
var usersNumber;
while (usersNumber = readline()) {
if (1 <= usersNumber && usersNumber <= 1000000000)
{

var inputBinary = usersNumber.toString(2);

var binaryArray = [];

for (i = 0; i < inputBinary.length; i++) {
    binaryArray[i] = inputBinary.charAt(i);
};

binaryArray.reverse();

var stringBinaryFromArray = "";

for (i = 0; i < binaryArray.length; i++) {
    stringBinaryFromArray = stringBinaryFromArray + binaryArray[i];
}
var digit = parseInt(stringBinaryFromArray, 2);

print(digit);
}
```

}

Comment: `readline` is not a standard JS function - can you detail more about exactly what you're trying to do, and what library you're using that provides it?  You say you've tried something - can you show that code?

Comment: Now is my code in the question above... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readline()` is not a standard Javascipt function. You can use `prompt()` instead

```
while (usersNumber = prompt())
```

You might need to change the input from a string to a number.

```
while (usersNumber = Number(prompt()))
```

On another note, there are built-in functions you can use instead of the loops you have. [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). You can even do it all in 1 line.

```
var stringBinaryFromArray = inputBinary.split('').reverse().join('');
```

Answer (score 0):

(line = readline()) both assign line AND returns the value returned by readline()

if readline() returns null, line is null and the loop stops

Comment: Thank you! Line is always null for me, bacause there is no way to write some input... Why is that?